# get child value of a sub-child in python 2.6.6

Tags: python, elementtree

I have XML like below and want to extract alarm id with its attachment name.

```xml
<alarms formatVersion="1">
  <alarm id="4">
    <startDate>2018-06-19 08:10:05.0 UTC</startDate>
    <alarmDate>2018-06-19 08:10:05.0 UTC</alarmDate>
    <type>1234567</type>
    <intense>50</intense>
    <attachments>
      <attachment filename="20180619.partials.55.1234567.1.csv.gz" mimeType="text/csv"/>
    </attachments>
  </alarm>
  <alarm id="5">
    <startDate>2018-05-19 09:10:05.0 UTC</startDate>
    <alarmDate>2018-05-19 08:10:05.0 UTC</alarmDate>
    <type>1234567</type>
    <intense>50</intense>
    <attachments>
        <attachment filename="20180519.payers.12.1015500.1.csv.gz" mimeType="text/csv"/>
    </attachments>
  </alarm>
  <alarm id="5">
    <startDate>2018-05-19 09:10:05.0 UTC</startDate>
    <alarmDate>2018-05-19 08:10:05.0 UTC</alarmDate>
    <type>1234567</type>
    <intense>50</intense>
  </alarm>
</alarms>
```

Code tried:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import gzip

input=gzip.open('input-xml.gz','r')
tree=ET.parse(input)
root=tree.getroot()


 for lsofals in root.findall("./alarm/"):
         print lsofals.attrib
         for atts in lsofals.findall('attachments'):
         print atts.getchildren()
               for aname in atts.findall('attachment filename'):
                       print aname.attrib
```

Required Sample output:

```
{4: 20180619.partials.55.1234567.1.csv.gz, 5:20180519.payers.12.1015500.1.csv.gz}
```

With present code I am able to get the value of alarm but unable to get the value of attachments which I am stuck as new to python. Post retrieving the value of attachment I need to form a dictionary which I will work once after solving this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With simple *element path*:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import gzip

input = gzip.open('input-xml.gz','r')
tree = ET.parse(input)
root = tree.getroot()

for att in root.findall("./alarm/attachments/attachment"):
    print(att.get('filename'))
```

The output:

```
20180619.partials.55.1234567.1.csv.gz
20180519.payers.12.1015500.1.csv.gz
```

---

If you need to get it as a dictionary:

```
...
d = {}
for alarm in root.findall("./alarm"):
    for att in alarm.findall("attachments/attachment"):
        d[alarm.get('id')] = att.get('filename')

print(d)
```

The output:

```
{'4': '20180619.partials.55.1234567.1.csv.gz', '5': '20180519.payers.12.1015500.1.csv.gz'}
```